# How to detect anyonic statistics without calculating Berry phase diretly?

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics, topological-order, topological-phase, anyons

My question is: given a model, it is possible to know if it can support a specific kind of anyon (like Fibonacci or Ising) without having to explicitly calculate the Berry phase after a braiding?

I've read examples of this calculation being done directly (like for the honeycomb model https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/11/9/093027/pdf) but it is really computationally expensive and difficult to replicate for bigger systems.

Comment: There are other types of invariants that can help diagnose what anyon theory it is, such as ground state degeneracy and topological entanglement entropy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any references to learn more about that? Any particular example?

Comment: @mengcheng But is not it that those properties only reveal if anyonic nature of a theory? How can one diagnose the degeneracy of ground states if the system has Fib or SU(2)_5?